# AWS Cloudformation nested intrinsic function not evaluating

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

This is part of the cloudformation template I am writing and getting errors using the `Fn::FindInMap` function:

```
Parameters:
  VpcStackName:
    Description: >-
      Name of an active CloudFormation VPC stack that contains the networking
      resources, such as the subnet and security group, that will be used in
      this stack.
    Type: String
    MinLength: 1
    MaxLength: 255
    AllowedPattern: '^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
    Default: wordpress-dev-vpc

Mappings:
  Instance:
    development:
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
    production:
      AllocatedStorage: 25
      DBInstanceClass: db.m3.medium

Resources:
  DBInstance:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
      Properties:
        Engine: MariaDB
        StorageType: gp2
        MasterUsername: !Ref MasterUsername
        MasterUserPassword: !Ref MasterUserPassword
        AllocatedStorage:
          Fn::FindInMap:
            - Instance
            - Fn::ImportValue:
                Fn::Sub: '${VpcStackName}-Environment'
            - AllocatedStorage
        DBInstanceClass:
          Fn::FindInMap:
            - Instance
            - Fn::ImportValue:
                Fn::Sub: '${VpcStackName}-Environment'
            - DBInstanceClass
```

In another stack, I am exporting `${VpcStackName}-Environment` like this:

```
Outputs:
  Environment:
    Description: Environment type of this stack
    Value: !Ref Environment
    Export:
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-Environment'
```

When trying to use the `Fn::FindInMap` function, I get this error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template error: every Fn::FindInMap object requires three parameters, the map name, map key and the attribute for return value
```

Any advice?

Based on the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html , the supported functions inside a `Fn::FindInMap` function are `Fn::FindInMap` and `Ref`. So is there another way to do it? For example, storing the value of `Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${VpcStackName}-Environment'` in a temporary variable?

Comment: Check if this export value is available ${AWS::StackName}-Environment, I tried the same template with hardcoded value and it works.

Comment: Yes, the export value is available. I used it successfully in another template where importing the value worked. For some reason, `Fn::ImportValue` is not getting evaluated inside `Fn::FindInMap`

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html) document, the `Fn::FindInMap` function is only usable with these:

- `Fn::FindInMap`
- Ref

So `Fn::ImportValue` and `Fn::Sub` won't be evaluated.